# Java DefaultTreeModel's removeNodeFromParent is removing the incorrect node

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a `JTree` which looks like the following:

[My JTree at runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNlEy.png)

I have a popup menu that appears whenever the user right-clicks a node on the `JTree`, which has a JMenuItem to delete the node:

```
public class DeleteMenuItem extends JMenuItem {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7772347171442949034L;
    private String menuItemText = "Delete";

    public DeleteMenuItem(DefaultTreeModel treeModel, DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode, FileNode fileNode) {
        super();

        this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                int userChoice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Delete " + fileNode.getFile().getName() + "?",
                        "Delete File", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                if (userChoice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    boolean successfullyDeletedFile = fileNode.getFile().delete();
                    if (successfullyDeletedFile) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully deleted " + fileNode.getFile().getName(),
                                "File Deleted", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        treeModel.removeNodeFromParent(treeNode);  // treeNode is the node I right clicked on and pressed delete on it is the one I need gone
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not delete " + fileNode.getFile().getName(),
                                "File Deletion Failed", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

        this.setText(this.menuItemText);
    }

}
```

However, it seems that when I right click the node and press delete:

[Pressing right click and then delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1nlF.png)

[Tree after deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6L9N.png)

I don't understand why this is happening as when i look in my file explorer the correct file that I right clicked on in the tree is deleted but the tree displays the file and seems to have deleted the parent node.

I know `treeNode` is the correct node as it has no children (I tested it) so it can't be that `treeNode` is not the correct node.

**How do I delete the correct node in my JTree?**

Comment: From what you provided us with I actually don't think your trying to fix the actual problem. Because you right click the "ProjectData.xml" Node, delete that and from the looks of it, that node was actually deleted as your last screenshot has that Node deleted. Now maybe I'm wrong and it actually deleted the wrong Node but for some reason it overwrote the display name of the Node, but would my guess be correct that you have an if condition where you assign the Node-Icons that says "if a parent node has ONE child only, assign the File-Icon, else assign the Folder-Icon" or some variation of that?

Comment: Is your problem the fact that the icon for `.pygs` changes from a folder to a file after deleting `ProjectData.xml`?

Comment: I agree with @yur and Abra it looks like the deletion and the code is working it’s just that when a node does not have any more children by default the icon goes to a file icon. All you need to do is force directory nodes to always have a folder icon.

Comment: @yur you are correct for some reason I did not even read the name of node and see that the correct one was deleted (because I was watching the icon). How do I force specific nodes to always have a certain icon no matter whether they have children or not.

Comment: @user14198949 You can check wether the `File` object you have is a file or a directory. You can call the methods `File.isDirectory()` or `File.isFile()` to check and then load the icon accordingly.